# Converting Swing app to web

Tags: java

I have Java code of the algorithm that has numeric values as its input and output. The GUI is implemented as Swing in Eclipse. Now I would like to tranfer to the web environment and create the web-tool using JavaScript or sth like this. Is there any way to use the Java code of my algorithm without rewriting it?

Answer (score 0):

if your logic and goi all together at the same class you need to remove all the GUI part and stay with all the logic. after you have logic class you can use what ever goi you want(swing, html, jsf....)

Comment: Yes, the logic is apart from GUI, of course:) But could you please provide web-link to some tutorial how to use JAVA with HTML?

Comment: http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf1/index.html
http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html
http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to skip the HTML part by hand and just create your HTML app in Java. No need for separate servlets serving Java validation to your HTML inputs. The open source framework Vaadin that we've been working on since 2001 and it has an almost 100% similar API to Swing could be an alternative for this for you. And it would hopefully save you a lot of time.

As a swing developer the most relevant starting point for you would be: https://vaadin.com/swing

Answer (score -1):

You can look up in to servlets and if you do it in netbeans then will be much easier for you.

Comment: Look in to a web based application where you can take input through html/jsp pages. Use servlets to do your backend work with your java code.